# not possible to import a class from my own jar i built with intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, import, jar, package, dependencies

i built a jar and installed it to my .m2 repository.

Then, in a second project (which i want to ne the consumer of the first one),
i put this in the pom.xml, as a dependency :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.coussy</groupId>
        <artifactId>reusable</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

All is ok, the dependence is recognized.
BUT, when i want to use one of the class,
1- Intellij propose me to import class via ALT + Enter
2- i press ALT + Enter but the class is never imported.

This is the same with the maven command

```
mvn compile
```

i got the message :

```
cannot find symbol
```

What do i have to do ?

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake.
I built my jar as a spring-boot dependency (it contained a BOOT-INF folder)
and not like a classical jar.

So i had to put this in my pom.xml to build a fat, independant jar.

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!--  bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Currently, i can import classes from  my new dependency without any problem.
Problem solved.